# TaxonomyFieldControl You must specify a valid field value

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store

I have a custom Manage Metadata field which is hooked up on a TermStore which has an **Open** Submission Policy and the field itself has **Allow multiple value** + **Fill-in choices** enabled (Checked).

Yet when I try to create or edit an item and fill-in a new term which I want in the termset, I get the error *You must specify a valid field value.*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new term is available through the "Add new item" link in the term picker dialog. It's access from the pair of luggage tags next to the term entry text box.

[image: An example Term Picker Dialog box with Add New Item link highlighted]

For more information, there is [a similar question and answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5230d013-9e68-4491-8ca3-b4b2096f9e88/how-to-let-users-add-their-own-metadata-tags) on the Microsoft SharePoint Forums.